# $request->route() returns null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
class TotersProviderLoginController extends Controller
{

    private $oauthService;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $provider = $request->route()->parameter('provider'); // error here
        if($provider == 'google')
            $this->oauthService = new GoogleOauthService();
        else
            throw new \Exception('Provider '.($provider ?? '').' not supported!');
    }
```

I have the following routes defined:

```
Route::get('login/toters/{provider}', 'Accounts\TotersProviderLoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/toters/{provider}/redirect', 'Accounts\TotersProviderLoginController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('login/toters/{provider}/csrf', 'Accounts\TotersProviderLoginController@getCsrf');
Route::post('login/toters/{provider}/oauth', 'Accounts\TotersProviderLoginController@requestToken');
```

for some reason when I run

```
php artisan route:list --verbose
```

I get this error

```
In TotersProviderLoginController.php line 38:

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to a member function parameter() on null
```

so it's clear that `$request->route()` is returning null. Why is that?
note: I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: Could it be that there is no request variable when using the artisan command?

Comment: Can you please try same logic in controller function instead of constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have debug myself as you mentioned in the question and i found the way where you get the error.

When you run `php artisan route:list --verbose` command it will debug all routes and also call controller methods of every routes.

In your case what happens when you run command with `verbose`, route do not have `provider` default value and that's why it always gives null value.

While you call routes via postman or web it will definitely work, because at that time you have always some value for `provider`.

Thanks:)